# iOS Launch Screen SVG problem with blurry rendering

Tags: iphone, ios16, launch-screen

I am trying to add an SVG image in an app's launch screen. The image has a gradient color and the launch screen appears perfectly on the simulator, but the image is rendered completely blurry on a physical device. Both the device and the simulator have iOS 16.4. What could be the problem?

Below is how the launch screen's SVG image looks on the physical device:

[image]